# Как достать ссылку из определенного тега средствами библиотеки JSOUP

Tags: java, json, jsoup

Необходимо достать ссылку на фильм при парсенге, с определенно тега, в данном случае

```
<h3><a href="/movie_796/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-return-of-the-king" class="titlefilm">Властелин колец 3: Возвращение Короля</a> <span class="bigtext">(The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King)</span>, 2003</h3>
```

Comment: Свой код уже есть или полностью надо за вас написать?

Comment: я могу достать с `<a href="/movie_796/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-return-of-the-king" class="titlefilm">Властелин колец 3: Возвращение Короля</a>` но он берет со всей страницы. Мне надо именно с <h3>

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < titleList.size(); i++) {
                    moviesUrl = docTxt.select("a").get(i);
                    moviesUrlList.add(moviesUrl.attr("href"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `h3 > a[href]` - поиск всех ссылок, дочерних для тега `h3`:

```
Elements links = doc.select("h3 > a[href]");
for (Element link : links) {
   System.out.println(String.format("a: <%s> (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), link.text()));
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < titleList.size(); i++) {
                    moviesUrl = docTxt.select("h3").select("a").get(i);
                    moviesUrlList.add(moviesUrl.attr("href"));
                }`Спасибо. Разобрался. Так тоже работает